# Symfony 4, when i ope public folder i have blank page after deployment

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I have developed an application in Symfony 4. The application works perfectly in localhost, with the command php -S 127.0.0.1:8000 -t public I see the application in localhost: 8000, but if I access localhost / nameproject / public I have a page white. I ran the commands composer install --no - dev --optimize - autoloader, export APP_ENV = prod, php bin / console cache: clear --env = prod --no - debug and composer require symfony / apache - pack. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the error, with php -v I return the 7.1.14 version, but with phpinfo () I found that I have in the php php version 5.6! I hope my experience can be useful to someone!